# Is it difficult to find for each case and finally add all?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There is a 6 letter word "FAMINE".

Question :

How many 6 letter words are there such that only 2 vowels are together ?

I attempted to solve it as

Total permutations = $6!$  = $720$

No of cases where all vowels are separated = $3! \times 4! $ = $144$

No of cases where all 3 vowels together      = $4! \times 3! $ = $144$

so

No of cases of only 2 vowels together = Total permutations - (No of cases where all vowels are separated + No of cases where all 3 vowels together )

= 720 - 144 - 144 
= 432

Now this was a easier way . This method was basically total - unwanted case

How can I do it without using the above method of subtracting other unwanted cases from total ?i.e., How can I do it directly by adding all wanted cases ?

Is it difficult to do it that way ?

Why I am asking this question is , here I will be able to do it this easier way , but in cases where there say 12 letters and have 6 vowels , to find the number of 12 letter words with 4 vowels together , I cannot do it in this method . So I wish learning how to solve such cases in the straight forward way(of adding all the possible wanted cases) like

if AE , how many cases

if EI , how many cases

if AI , how many cases

then add all to get answer .

How can I do it in the above mentioned way ? Please help .

Thanks

Comment: I am completely puzzled by your existing calculations. Are you specifically interested in anagrams of "FAMINE", rather than other six-letter words like "RHYTHM"?

Comment: (Even if so I am failing to follow your logic, and perhaps you could explain a little clearer where $3! \times 4!$ comes from, for example)

Comment: @BenMillwood I'm not sure whether this is how it was done, but the numbers are right. For vowels separated, arrange three consonants, and three vowels plus a blank (=4 items) in the pattern VCVCVCV to get $3!\cdot 4!$. For three vowels together, there are $3!$ ways to order the vowels, $3!$ ways to order the consonants and four slots in which to place the vowels - also giving $3!\cdot 4!$.

Comment: to @BenMillwood 3! * 4! is because when all vowels are together 3! ways of arranging them within group , this group as a whole ia permuted with the rest of consonents so  4 units . so 4! .. so net is 3! * 4!

Comment: to @BenMillwood when all are separate so vowels should come between consonants , so four places where vowels can go (because there are 3 consonants . so 4C3 * 3! * 3! = 4! * 3!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways of choosing a pair of vowels to go together. The pair and the single vowel must be separated by at least one consonant, and there are three consonants - so they must fit in the pattern VCVCVCV.

There are $3!$ ways of placing the consonants, $3$ ways of choosing the pair of vowels to go together, $2$ orders for that pair, $\binom 42$ ways of choosing the two slots for the pair and the single vowel, and two ways of arranging them in those slots.

$$3!\cdot 3 \cdot 2\cdot \binom 42\cdot 2 = 6^3\cdot 2 =432$$

Comment: What do you mean by the pattern VCVCVCV?

Comment: [vowel or pair or blank][consonant][vowel or pair or blank][consonant][vowel or pair or blank][consonant][vowel or pair or blank] - $7$ slots into which five items must be fitted. The consonants go in the consonant slots and this ensures that the vowels are separated, because there are not two vowel slots together.

Comment: @MarkBennet , I am literally awestruck by the way you solved this problem . How did you solve this problem . I thought of getting each case AE , EI , AI and adding it . Your sequential way of solving is really great and it is more logical. Is this sequential way of doing applicable in most places ?

Comment: @MarkBennet .Question 2 : Can you suggest some good books where I can read permutation and combination so that I can also solve such problem with so much ease with which you solved it? I don't have words to appreciate your method of solving .You are God .

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam - I don't know any good books. I learned to do this various ways from when I was at high school. At university I remember we had a lecture on how to count. I've always loved puzzles. This solution was based on something I noticed on this site last week! You can search for all the combinatorics or permutations questions on the site - and what you get more than in a book is a range of practical ways of dealing with problems. You might get three different ways of tackling the same problem. Some will depend on special features, others will apply more widely. A great way to learn